# How to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=n}^\infty x_i = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

Let $\{ x_i \}$ be a decreasing sequence of non-negative real numbers such that $\sum_i x_i < \infty$.

How do I argue that

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=n}^\infty x_i = 0
\end{align}

Comment: What is $x$ in the expression $\sum_{i} x+i$?

Comment: sorry again should be $\sum_i x_i < \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:

Let $$S=\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i$$

Then, $$\sum_{i=n}^\infty x_i = S - \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i$$

Now, take the limits of both sides.

Comment: sorry edited question

Comment: @jason I edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

The statement seems very much false.

$$x_i>0 \hspace{4pt} \forall \hspace{2pt} i$$
$$\Rightarrow \sum_{i=n}^\infty x_i>0$$

Comment: That's a pretty bad argument. Just because a sequence is positive, that doesn't mean the limit cannot be zero.

Comment: In the original statement you said positive real number. If every number is positive then their sum is positive too. Now you changed it to non-negative and this changes everything

Comment: No, it doesn't. $\frac1n$ is a positive real number, but that doesn't mean $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n$ is a positive real number.