# Does this series converge to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does $|x_k|$ $\to$ $0$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_k| < \infty$ $\implies$ $\sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty} |x_k| \to 0$ as $m\to\infty$ ?

If so, how would one formally prove this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2220495/42969. – Note that his holds for all convergent series, not only for series of absolute values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$\sum_{k=m+1}^{\infty} |x_k| = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_k| - \sum_{k=1}^{m} |x_k| $$